# Como fazer um preview de uma imagem carregada em um input do tipo "file"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Descrição:**

---

Tenho um exemplo aqui de como esta funcionando o meu sistema.
[Link do EXEMPLO](http://jsfiddle.net/VzfJd/2/)

---

**HTML**

```
<input type=file>
<input type=button class=hide value="Adicionar outro">
```

---

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function verificaMostraBotao(){
    $('input[type=file]').each(function(index){
        if ($('input[type=file]').eq(index).val() != ""){
            $('.hide').show();
        }
    });
}

$('input[type=file]').on("change", function(){
  verificaMostraBotao();
});

$('.hide').on("click", function(){
    $(document.body).append($('<input />', {type: "file" }).change(verificaMostraBotao));
    $('.hide').hide();
});
```

---

**CSS**

```
input[type=file] {
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
    float: left;
}
```

---

**Necessidade:**

---

Quero implementar um `preview` nesse código. Cada `input` exibir o `preview` do seu lado;

É possível?

Comment: Vejo que estás continuando aquele exemplo que perguntaste ontem ;)

Comment: Sim @PauloRoberto (Y)

Comment: Bom!!! Eu lhe aconselho a usar plugins, para essas situações pois os plugins ajudam a reduzir o tempo de desenvolvimento... ou seja, você terá mais tempo para focar-se na regra de negocio do seu projecto... Para o teu caso pode usar o *[ezdz jquery](http://js-tutorial.com/ezdz-turn-input-type-file-into-a-nice-drag-drop-zone-920)*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente pegar o valor do input e jogar como src de uma imagem, apenas adicione esta função ao seu exemplo:

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
        $(input).next()
        .attr('src', e.target.result)
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
    else {
        var img = input.value;
        $(input).next().attr('src',img);
    }
}
```

## Observação(mudei o HTML, adicionei um `<img>` de preview para cada um):

```html
<input type=file>
<img />
<input type=button class=hide value="Adicionar outro">
```

Mudei também o evento `$('.hide').on("click")`:

```
$('.hide').on("click", function(){
    $(document.body).append($('<input />', {type: "file" }).change(verificaMostraBotao));
    $(document.body).append($('<img />'));
    $('.hide').hide();
});
```

**Obs:** Note que agora eu coloco uma `<img>` para se tornar o preview de cada elemento.

Chame a função `readURL()` no evento `.change()` do seu input verificando primeiramente se não está vazio o value:

```
function verificaMostraBotao(){
    $('input[type=file]').each(function(index){
        if ($('input[type=file]').eq(index).val() != ""){
            readURL(this);
            $('.hide').show();
        }
    });
}
```

## [Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VzfJd/10/)

## [Referência](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16207641/2319589)

## Compatibilidade:

**(Referência da resposta do @GuilhermeBernal)** - Isso só funciona em navegadores que suportam a [FileReader API](http://caniuse.com/filereader) (que implica em IE10+)

Comment: Isso mesmo @PauloRoberto, só que queria que cada input teria sua imagem. Entende?

Comment: Pronto @JeffersonAlison :)

Comment: Isso o que precisava! E @PauloRoberto, estou te devendo umas! hehehe

Comment: hahaha, pois é cara, já te salvei bastante, vou começar a cobrar ein? :p

Comment: kkkkkk, valeu irmão!

Comment: Paulo, por gentileza, não abusando da sua vontade... mas tu pode ver esse fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/ZGUQA/1/ ... as imagens duplicam depois do primeiro input

Comment: Vish amigo o que foi que você fez com meu código?? hahaha, foi dificil entender o seu Fiddle, sério cara... te aconselho a fazer denovo, usando a lógica que estou te dando aqui na resposta, leia ela denovo e tente fazer algo melhor, evite dar append em strings html, pois isso gera dificuldade de entender seu código, separe os html's em elementos e depois de append neles. PORÉM como eu sou um cara muito legal, eu arrumei seu fiddle, toma aí http://jsfiddle.net/ZGUQA/3/

Comment: Caaraleo, véi tu é o cara!! Ja estou a dias tentando fazer isso.. Tu sabe né, toda hora estou perguntando pra mim tentar fazer sozinho hehe. Obrigado pelas dicas ai e pelo codigo! Valeu mesmo brother!

Answer (score 8):

Fazendo uso da [API FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>, podes ler o endereço que se encontra no `input` do tipo `file` e recolher os dados binários para posteriormente injectar na página:

#### Função

Na função em baixo, estamos a ler o conteúdo do `input` do tipo `file` e após sua conclusão criamos um novo elemento DOM `img` ao qual atribuímos os dados lidos. Por fim, anexamos o elemento à página actual, logo após o `input` em questão.

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $img = $('<img/>').attr('src', e.target.result);
            $(input).after($img);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

#### O teu caso prático

Para o teu caso prático, em adição da função em cima, é preciso uma pequena alteração ao código que tens, de forma a que o uso da API seja realizado também nos elementos que crias dinamicamente.

Onde estás a anexar o evento `change`:

```
$('input[type=file]').on("change", function(){
    verificaMostraBotao();
});
```

Vamos alterar para uma delegação, neste caso a partir do `body`:

```
$('body').on("change", "input[type=file]", function(){
    verificaMostraBotao();
    readURL(this);
});
```

Garantindo assim que novos `input` criados pela tua função possam fazer o preview do ficheiro escolhido.

---

## Código Final

O código todo junto fica conforme pode ser visto em baixo e no JSFiddle:

[**Exemplo a funcionar no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/QtzzL/)

#### HTML

```
<input type="file">
<input type="button" class="hide" value="Adicionar outro">
```

#### jQuery

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $img = $('<img/>').attr('src', e.target.result);
            $(input).after($img);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

function verificaMostraBotao() {
    $('input[type=file]').each(function(index){
        if ($('input[type=file]').eq(index).val() != "")
            $('.hide').show();
    });
}

$('body').on("change", "input[type=file]", function() {
    verificaMostraBotao();
    readURL(this);
});

$('.hide').on("click", function() {
    $(document.body).append($('<input />', {type: "file" }).change(verificaMostraBotao));
    $('.hide').hide();
});
```

---

<sup>Créditos da função `readURL`, na sua forma mais simples, para o @Ivan Baev no SOEN [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4459419/352449).</sup>

Comment: Legal, tua resposta tem mais ou menos a mesma ideia que a minha porém utiliza caminhos diferentes :D - é bom ter métodos diferentes para comparar

Comment: no chrome nao é mais possivel pegar o caminho da imagem do input e colocar no ```src=""``` de uma ```<img>``` porque o chrome  agora mostra um "fakepath"

Comment: Como reduzir a img (por exemplo para height = 50px) A sua resposta foi perfeita para meu problema. Grato

Comment: @Geo Onde criamos a imagem, podemos definir a largura. Troca este código `$img = $('<img/>').attr('src', e.target.result);` por `$img = $('<img/>').attr('src', e.target.result).attr('style', 'width:50px');` e deve resolver o problema.

Answer (score 5):

Sabendo que isso só funciona em navegadores que suportam a [FileReader API](http://caniuse.com/filereader) (que implica em IE10+), você pode fazer o seguinte para ler o arquivo e como um DataURI, setando o `src` de uma imagem.

```
function readImage() {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        var file = new FileReader();
        file.onload = function(e) {
            document.getElementById("preview").src = e.target.result;
        };       
        file.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
}

document.getElementById("imgChooser").addEventListener("change", readImage, false);
```

Exemplo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VzfJd/4/).

Comment: Todo mundo respondeu no mesmo minuto, você ganhou por 40 segundos.

Comment: Obrigado @GuilhermeBernal