# Como fazer um preview de uma imagem carregada em um input do tipo “file”?

Tags: image

Através de um input, gostaria de carregar uma imagem na mesma pagina e com as propriedades nas configurações abaixo. No caso, a imagem apareceria em cima do input para o cliente fazer um preview dela.

```html
<img src="" alt="" width="340" height="230" style="border-radius: 10px; 
    border-color: black;" border="2px"/>

<input id="filebutton" name="filebutton" type="file">
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Preview de imagem antes do Upload + ImageResizing.net](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11837/preview-de-imagem-antes-do-upload-imageresizing-net)

Comment: Ou então https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86520/preview-de-imagem-com-js

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como fazer um preview de uma imagem carregada em um input do tipo "file"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6898/como-fazer-um-preview-de-uma-imagem-carregada-em-um-input-do-tipo-file)