# Como eu uso o input file para upar uma imagem e colocar ela numa div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, dom

Olá, queria saber se alguém pode me ajudar.
Eu tenho essa div "form-img" que recebe um input para upar imagens e eu queria que quando eu upasse a imagem, ela aparecesse cobrindo essa div.

Eu tentei de algumas formas pegar o caminho do arquivo usando JS e eu queria colocar ele no SRC do meu HTML, mas nao tive sucesso.
Depois disso eu fiz algumas pesquisas e vi que o navegador não permitia que eu tivesse acesso ao caminho dos arquivos e agora eu não sei mais o que faço :c

Esse é meu HTML

```
<div class="formulary">
  <div class="form-img">
    <label for="form-img-upload">Upload cover (270 x 400)</label>
    <input
      id="form-img-upload"
      name="form-img-upload"
      type="file"
      accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg"
      style="display: none"
    />
    <img id="form-img-uploaded" src="#" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Esse é meu CSS

```
  .form-img {
    height: 400px;
    width: 270px;
    background-color: #222028;
    border-radius: 6px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .form-img label {
    padding: 180px 50px;
    transition: 0.4s ease;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  }

  .form-img label:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
  }
```

Comment: Relacionado: [Erro ao carregar uma imagem de um arquivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/362864/3774)

Comment: Resposta do Guilherme Bernal explica sobre a File API: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6900/3635